# How to display code if it is not certain pages?

Tags: pages, page-template

Im trying to set up an if statement to display certain code, if the user is on a certain page. I've got the links and student work pages to work, but when I add the if not link and not student work I get an unexpected T_BOOLEAN_AND error. How can I fix this so I can list the pages I don't want custom code for and use just page.php

```
<?php 
            if (!is_page('links')) && (!is_page('student-work'))  {
                include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/pages/page.php');
            } elseif (is_page('links')) {
                query_posts('cat=2');
                include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/pages/links.php');
            } elseif (is_page('student-work')) {
                query_posts('cat=4');
                include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/pages/student-work.php');
            }
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

I just used this code and it works for me. Hopefully it solves your problem.

```
if( ! is_page( array( 'links', 'student-work' ) ) ) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: Could you [edit your answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/254136/edit) and expand upon why this solves OPs question and supply any links that supports how this solves the problem please?

Answer (score 3):

This is really just PHP, not WP, but your initial if statement has an extra parenthesis after `!is_page('links')`, so the `&&` is outside and PHP doesn’t know what to do with it. It'd be better to reorganize the block anyway, e.g.

```
<?php 
        if (is_page('links')) {
            query_posts('cat=2');
            include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/pages/links.php');
        } elseif (is_page('student-work')) {
            query_posts('cat=4');
            include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/pages/student-work.php');
        }
        else  {
            include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/pages/page.php');
        }
?>
```

In terms of WordPress, you'd probably be better off using page-specific template files, such as `page-links.php or page-student-work.php`. You could also use `get_template_part()` instead of includes to accomplish what that if/else block does in just one line if you need to keep this all in one file for some reason.